# mamp make the filenames case insensitive

Tags: apache, case-sensitive, mamp, case-insensitive

in mamp which uses apache is there a way to make the files names filenames case insensitive?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after locating where to disable the speling_module under the mamp pro apache server admin, this problem was fixed.

Comment: I've disabled that module in my MAMP Pro, 2.x but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: is this in issue with version 2? are you still having the problem?

Comment: I will have to give mine an upgrade this weekend and see if I can replicate your problem